# A major in a C# major progression

Tags: chords, chord-progressions, ear-training

I am trying to understand why in a progression in C# major there is an A major chord, the chords are to be precise: C# Bbm F# A, where did this A come from?

I thought it might be a secondary dominant that does not resolve but still, A would resolve on a D which is not present in the C# scale, so why does it fit in this key?

The song is "gua10" by "tha Supreme & Lazza", the chords in question are the first four at the beginning of the song and are repeated throughout, **the song is in the key of C# major.**

Comment: A#m would probably be a better name than Bbm, given key C#.

Comment: Have you tried writing your own melodies over the chords? Which notes seem to fit over the A chord?

Comment: @Tim but D flat major would probably be a better name for the key in the first place (making the A major chord a B double-flat major chord, of course).

Comment: @Tim Sorry for my mistake but I don't know that part of the theory, in this regard, where can I study the sharps and flats of the various scales, how this part of theory is called?

Comment: @Salmone It is hard to make a recommendation without knowing what you already do know. However, if you know that the scale of C# major has 7 sharps, it suffices to say that all chords that can be formed within the scale are spelled using the notes from the scale (and the notes from A#m are, whereas those from Bbm clearly aren’t). If you don’t know that, you need to first study key signatures and the circle of fifths.

Comment: @11684 Hi, what I don't know is when a scale has sharps and when has flats, for example G major has F# or Gb? What is the rule?

Comment: @Salmone then you need to study key signatures and the circle of fifths. Also, in major and minor scales each letter appears exactly once. You couldn’t have Gb in a G major scale, because you would then have G twice (once flat and once natural) and no f (skipping from e to Gb). But all this becomes clear when you see the derivation from the circle of fifths.

Comment: Another transcription question disguised as a theory question. The only way to answer is first fix the transcription errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a very common thing, mixing in harmony from the parallel key. It doesn't necessarily move the tonic anywhere, but it opens the door for it. In this song they never use that option.

Two variations of the same idea:

- C# A#m F# F#m (use F#m instead of A)
- C# A#m F# A/B

If you want to test the parallel-key hypothesis, don't go back to C#, but take advantage of the opened door and move to the suggested E major:

- C# A#m F# A ... E C#m A C

and why not continue even further

- C# A#m F# A ... E C#m A C ... G Em C Eb ... Bb Gm Eb F# ... start over

To really explicate the key changes:

- C# A#m F# A/B ... E C#m A C/D ... G Em C Eb/F ... Bb Gm Eb F#/G#

Comment: Where did the 'suggested E major' come from? Did you mean D major?

Comment: @Tim It's in C# and mixes in stuff from C# minor, suggesting a possible move one-and-a-half steps up --> E major. With the proper bass it's more obvious, C# A#m F# A/B ... E C#m A C/D ... G Em C Eb/F ... Bb Gm Eb F#/G# ... repeat.

Comment: Aah, suggested by the music, not by OP... although, as in my answer, that A sometimes leads straight to D.

Comment: @Tim Actually, I got the idea straight from the chord symbols, it's a common trick, I use things like that all the time to beef up boring songs. Alternate between, say, C# and A major chords, it pumps between C# and C# minor. Or it doesn't even have to use an E note it can use E#. With notes C# - D# - E# - F# - G# - A - B, the intervals around C# are partly from major and partly from minor.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica Thank you, I don't understand one little thing, why an A major suggests to go to E major? As a secondary dominant it suggests to go in D major but why in E?

Comment: AKA chromatic mediants and submediants

Comment: @Salmone Did you try the alternative versions, one that goes from A to E, or from A/B to E? A/B means that over a B bass note there's an A chord. Maybe "suggest" was not the best word, but when I hear the A chord, I immediately expect the good old major/minor mixture trick. Going to D is not near the top of my list of expectations, even though an A chord of course makes that a plausible option as well. In my mind, the tonic is set to C#, and an A major in that situation is, to me, a modal mixture as the first interpretation. I feel that relative keys are two sides of one dual key.

Comment: @Salmone Maybe I wasn't clear ... since C# minor and E major, being relative minor and major, are kind of the same thing and go hand-in-hand, then mixing in things from C# minor into C# major is the same as mixing in things from E major. Relative minor and major are so tighty connected in the music I make and am used to, I don't consider a shift-of-balance from C#m to E any sort of "modulation".

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica Ok so it is like: we are in C#, we take A major from the parallel key which is also E major, so E major seems nice since is the tonic of the key from where we are taking a new chord, so we can even put a C# minor after the A major instead of E major.

Comment: @Salmone - C#m quite often does follow A in songs.

Comment: @Tim Ok thanks, about the progression he wrote with the bass notes, for example A/B, why does it explicate the key change? Because B is the 5th grade of E major? So in C major a chord of F/G resolves better than a simply F on C?

Comment: @Salmone In C major, F/G works as a replacement for G7. It doesn't have the leading tone B in it, but it works nevertheless. You should now go and try all these in different songs and develop a feeling for the chords. It's not possible to learn music as a list of things to remember. Did you try the bass note versions, did they feel any different?

Answer (score 7):

It's often considered that the A here would come from the *parallel* key of C♯ *minor*. It's a fairly well used contraption, using notes and chords from the key (major or minor) which has the same root, here C♯.

It is quite often used as the dominant of the key one semitone above (here, D), so doesn't really come into the secondary dominant category - unless there is that actual key change into key D, in which case it would belong to the new key more than the previous one - and not be secondary dominant, but simply dominant.

Answer (score 6):

Let’s take this to C major to be less confusing. Then we’d have C - Am - F - Ab. Ab can be seen as low altered mediant of C, which is not an uncommon thing to do. Basically what you’re doing there is to take the mediant from the minor scale instead of the major scale.

Comment: I mostly find talking about as if the key were C major to be *more* confusing, not less. But that’s probably just my personal preference. Sometimes the chord based on the sixth scale degree is called the submediant to distinguish it from chord based on the third degree

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking at it in Db major.

This makes the analysis a lot easier and is the key that it would be written in in a chart

*(Others are writing about it in C# major because you’ve asked that way, but unless you’ve modulated from another key, you wouldn’t use that key in most situations.)*

From a quick listen I would transcribe this progression as Db, Db7/Cb, Gb, Gbm/Bbb.
Here, the last chord is the 4 chord, but minor instead of major. This gives it a nostalgic kinda feel.

Here are some links to videos describing how this is used:

Comment: In my progression A is not the 4th grade of Db, A is not in the major scale of Db

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake and should have clarified:

The 'A' is there, but it's the 3rd of the Gbm chord, being played in first inversion. Because it's a Gbm chord, it's spelled as Bbb (B double flat).

Comment: Sorry I still can't understand, the 4th of Db isn't Gb? Which is different from A? In my chord progression I've got an A major as the last chord.

Comment: In Db major, Gb is the fourth note in the scale. Building a chord upon that gives you a major chord, but then the artist alters it by flattening the 3rd (Bb) to Bbb (which sounds the same as an A).

What you're thinking is an 'A', is actually part of this minor chord - is it not the root, but the 3rd. Here it is spelled as a Bbb.

He then takes that note, and puts it in the bass, making it a first inversion chord. If you aren't familiar with inversions there are lots of resources online.

Comment: Don't we need an E note to obtain an A? A Gbm is different from A chord

Comment: The chord isn't an A, it's a Gbm. The 'A' (written as a Bbb) is the third of Gbm dropped down into the bass.

Comment: @Salmone - in the first video, he explains a m69 voicing around the 3:42 mark... Instead, if you think of it as a Gbm7 (notes Gb-Bbb aka A- Db - E), use Bbb on the bass, and skip the Gb (rootless voicing) we get the notes of the A chord... this is just one way of looking at it, but totally valid

Comment: I understood, I didn't understand we were talking about a little different chord progression but now I notice something strange, why A major chord and Gbm/Bbb sounds both good as the last chord although there is an F# note in Gbm which is not in A chord (A chord with F# note is an A6 I think)? I mean, they are different chords but they both sound nice.